# Exclude directory for authentication with CAS Server

Tags: java, cas

I am using CAS server for authentication for my application. I want one directory to exclude for authentication. How can I do ?

Comment: can you show the source code what you are tried?

Comment: I couldn't find anything just to try also.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure with your CAS client (Jasig client, Spring Security client or Shiro client) what directories of your application should be protected or not.

Comment: How can I do that? I am looking for some tutorial or examples. Please Help.